# How can I write to only one user with an existing WebSocket connection instead of to all users?

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, chat, ktor

Here's what I have:
Here, incoming messages are sent to all users.

```
fun Route.chatSocket(roomController: RoomController) {
    webSocket("/chat-socket" ) {
        val session = call.sessions.get<ChatSession>()
        if (session==null) {
            close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.VIOLATED_POLICY,"No session"))
            return@webSocket
        }
        try {
            roomController.onJoin(
            username = session.username,
            sessionId = session.sessionId,
            socket = this
        )
       incoming.consumeEach { frame ->
            if (frame is Frame.Text) {
                roomController.sendMessage(
                    senderUsername = session.username,
                    message = frame.readText()
                )
            }

        }

        } catch (e: MemberAlredyExistExpetion) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
        } finally {
            roomController.tryDisconnect(session.username)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the roomController:

```
class RoomController(
    private val messageDataSource: MessageDataSource
) {
    private val members = ConcurrentHashMap<String,Member>()

    fun onJoin(
        username:String,
        sessionId:String,
        socket: WebSocketSession
    ) {
        if (members.containsKey(username)) {
            throw MemberAlredyExistExpetion()
        }
        members[username] = Member(
            username = username,
            sessionId = sessionId,
            socket  = socket
        )
    }

   suspend fun sendMessage(senderUsername: String, message: String) {
        members.values.forEach { member ->
            val messageEntity = Message(
                text = message,
                username = senderUsername,
                timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            )
            messageDataSource.insertMessage(messageEntity)

            val parsedMessage = Json.encodeToString(messageEntity)
            member.socket.send(Frame.Text(parsedMessage))
        }
    }
```

Here I have tried to implement a command with which I can write directly to a user. But it don`t work.

```
fun Route.chatToOne(roomController: RoomController) {
    webSocket("/whisper") {
        val session = call.sessions.get<ChatSessionToOne>()
        if (session==null) {
            close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.VIOLATED_POLICY,"No Session"))
            return@webSocket
        }
        try {
            incoming.consumeEach { frame ->
                if (frame is Frame.Text) {
                    roomController.sendMessageToOneUser(
                        senderUsername = session.username,
                        targetUsername = session.targetusername,
                        message = frame.readText()
                    )
                }
            }
        } catch (e: MemberAlredyExistExpetion) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
        }
    }
}
```

And here the code from the roomController:

```
suspend fun sendMessageToOneUser(senderUsername: String, targetUsername :String, message: String) {
        members.values.forEach { member ->
            if (member.username == targetUsername) {
                val messageEntity = Message(
                    text = message,
                    username = targetUsername,
                    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
                )
                messageDataSource.insertMessage(messageEntity)

                val parsedMessage = Json.encodeToString(messageEntity)
                member.socket.send(Frame.Text(parsedMessage))
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I write to only one user with an existing WebSocket connection instead of to all users?

Comment: In the `consumeEach` block you can call `outgoing.send` to send a frame to a client of the current session. Could you please try to comment all other code out to check it in isolation?